# Debugging Chrome Javascript engine source code from Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, es6-promise, v8

I have some sample JS code that I am running in the browser and it uses Promise. I would like to debug the source code of the JS engine along with debugging my source code. Is there a way I can attach the JS engine source code in chrome developer tools?

**UPDATE:**

```
 const buyFlightTicket = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const error = false;
                if (error) {
                    reject("Sorry your payment was not successful")
                } else {
                    resolve("Thank you, your payment was successful");
                }
            }, 3000)
        })
    }
    buyFlightTicket()
        .then((success) => console.log(success))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

I have this piece of code and I want to understand what the Promise() function is doing with the function I am passing it as argument

Comment: The developper tools in chrome include a debugger, is there something you would like to do that's not possible with that?

Comment: @MathieuK. — They said they wanted to debug V8 itself, not just JS running on it.

Comment: I would like to be able to put a breakpoint inside the Engine source code and do some debugging

Comment: my bad, I didn't get that.

Comment: What problem do you face with promises that makes you want to debug the engine internals?

Comment: @Bergi I have updated the issue with details

Comment: "*I want to understand what the Promise() function is doing*" - is [reading the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) not enough? It's simply calling the executor callback immediately. I doubt reading the highly-optimised engine source code will help.

Comment: @Bergi, I understood that its called back immediately through some tests, but there were some questions about the resolve and reject arguments that were passed to the function;  Are they being set to something internally? I am somewhat new to JS; so felt its good to be able to get access to the source code to be clear

Comment: Yes, the promise constructor passes in two resolving functions as arguments to the executor, which you can (should) call to resolve/reject the promise later. I would suggest you read some promise tutorials to learn the basics, if you want the gory details (or because you learn better that way) I'd suggest you rather read the EcmaScript specification than the source code of an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

V8 developer here. To debug V8 itself, you need a C++ debugger (like GDB or LLDB or Visual Studio's debugger), along with a Debug build of Chrome or V8. Chrome DevTools can't debug V8's internals.